# Bind Method Of One Object To Another

Tags: python, methods, types, instance

I'm having an error binding a method from one object to another.

A simple guess as to whats going on...I believe that the error I'm getting is due to the bark method still being bound to the original object. Therefor two self's are inserted into the hd.bark() function.

**EDIT:**

My goal here is maintain the buissness logic of 'post processing function' of a a data loading strategy while swapping strategy objects... I know this is not a good practice yet this is a small hack to get some command line functionality

```
import types
from copy import deepcopy
class Dog(object):
    def bark(self):
        print 'bark bark bark'

class Husky(object):
    def bark(self):
        print 'ruff ruff'

def borderBark(self):
    print 'border bark'
d = Dog()
d.bark()

h = Husky()
h.bark()

b = Dog()
b.bark = types.MethodType(borderBark,b)
b.bark()

hd = Husky()
bark = types.MethodType(deepcopy(d.bark),None, Husky)
print d.bark
print bark
hd.bark = types.MethodType(bark,hd,Husky)
print hd.bark
hd.bark()
```

Outputs:

```
bark bark bark
ruff ruff
border bark
<bound method Dog.bark of <__main__.Dog object at 0x000000004D9EC0B8>>
<unbound method Husky.bark>
<bound method Husky.bark of <__main__.Husky object at 0x00000000599616D8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-50-1279b42a4bd2>", line 29, in <module>
    hd.bark()

TypeError: bark() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Also, is `borderBark` part of `class Husky`?

Comment: I'm monkey patching a function at run time and swapping out a method allocated in another part of the code. Ie this is so that i can use the same function to do work, but be able to swap which data I'm using.

Comment: Thanks by the way for taking a look :)

Comment: @sal I've edited the description to reflect your question

Comment: I am not very sure I understand the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the correct way to do this... Since bound methods are wrapped functions you must find the unbound method via d.bark.im_func

```
hd = Husky()
hd.bark = types.MethodType( d.bark.im_func ,hd,Husky)
hd.bark()
```